# Autocomplete working on localhost, but not on server ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have Autocomplete text box , working on local host but on server not

give this error :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
for this :jquery-1.10.2.js
I use IIS , and I check the publish code the jquery exist

this is my script

```
<script>

        $(function () {
            var availableTutorials;



            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetRecord1/',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                data: availableTutorials,
                success: function (data) {
                    availableTutorials = data;

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error " + xhr + "," + status + "," );
                }
            });


            $("#MyId").autocomplete({
                source: availableTutorials,
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 3
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is the link that I use

```
<link href="~/Scripts/ui-lightness-jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/new-jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

all of this is exist on correct path under  script file

where is the problem ?

Comment: Note you should never ever use `async: false`. It is a horrible practice and has been deprecated in browsers for a few years now. You should be seeing deprecation notices in your browser dev tools console

Comment: Check the network tab under developer tools, you should see a failed request to the `jquery-1.10.2.js`. Copy the URL and paste it on a new tab. Does it open? It probably won't. Now try to find why. Is it a well-formed URL? Is the path what you expected? Did the file actually get published? If you're on linux, it could be because of case sensitivity. If you're on IIS, maybe it's not serving it, and you need to fix your web.config. Do make an edit to your question to include everything you've tried.

Comment: async: false cause the problem ?

Comment: edited , fix web config ? what I can  do ?